# Version conflict when updating to play-services-analytics:9.6.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-analytics

I've downloaded the latest repositories at this moment for Android Studio 2.2. And want to update google analytics to the latest.
So, I have the option to upgrade play-services-analytics:9.6.0 but I'm having conflicts with the gms google-services version which I currently have it on 3.0.0 as I haven't found a newer version.

So here is what I have in my App gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.0'
```

This is what I have in my project dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Here is the build error message I'm getting:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

The only way I can make this work is using play-services-analytics:9.0.0, and so I get a deprecated warning.

Is there a way to fix this problem at this moment or do I have to wait until the next version of google-services?

Comment: did you find a fix to this?

Comment: @user1624194 yes I did, make sure you have the following setup.
- On the project gradle
-- dependencies { classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' }
- On the app gradle
-- dependencies { .... 
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
  ....}
-- apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
Make sure apply plugin for google-services is at the end of the gradle file (and not on top of the file)